# Cell change event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an Excel application to validate the VAT return.

I wanted it to validate the data as the user fills it.

Is there a way to make excel fire an event after a cell is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Worksheet_Change`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612